# How to map word combinations in python

Tags: python

Lets say I have a 2 word combination:

```
two flowers
```

I want to map possible combinations of these words programatically.  I have the following pseudocode combinations:

```
{fw}{lw}  (firstword, last word)
{fw} {lw}  (firstword, space, last word)
......
```

What is the best way in python to build up a shorthand notation like above, what data structure should it be stored in, and finally how would one map:

```
 two flowers x [{fw}{lw},{fw} {lw}] -> ['twoflowers','two flowers'] etc
```

I'm sorry this is kind of an open ended question. I'm pretty new to python and not sure how to approach this problem, so any advice would be appreciated. I put square brackets around the structures even though lists may not be the best data structure to use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've described is already built into Python (unless you're somehow on a version before 2.6):

```
>>> '{fw} {lw}'.format(fw='hello', lw='world')
'hello world'
```

or equivalently

```
>>> inputs = {'fw': 'hello', 'lw': 'world'}
>>> '{fw} {lw}'.format(**inputs)
'hello world'
```

(The `**` here takes a dict and uses it to set a function's keyword arguments.)  See the [standard library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) for more.

To iterate over a number of formats, you can use a standard for loop, or to be slick a *list comprehension*:

```
>>> format_strings = ['{fw}{lw}', '{fw} {lw}']
>>> [format_string.format(**inputs) for format_string in format_strings]
['helloworld', 'hello world']
```

**Update:** upon rereading your question it sounds like you might prefer the positional version of the above, which looks like this:

```
>>> '{0} {1}'.format('hello', 'world')
'hello world'
>>> inputs = ['hello', 'world']  # or 'hello world'.split()
>>> '{0} {1}'.format(*inputs)
'hello world'
```

The `*` is a lot like the `**`: instead of using a dict to set keyword arguments, it is using a list (or tuple) to set positional arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to mind is a dictionary of tuples.

```
yourdict = {'two flowers': ('twoflowers','two flowers')}
```

To get there, you could just regex out the space between. If it's only two words, and there should be only one space, it shouldn't be difficult to do.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I was simplifying , but I'm going to have many2 -3 words and there could be a dozen or so permutations which I want to be able to write a shorthand notation for.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
dict_combinations = {"{fw}{lw}":lambda x : x.replace(" ", ""), "{fw} {lw}": lambda x:" ".join(x.split())}

list_words = ["text flower", "hello friend"]
result =[map(method, list_words) for key,method in dict_combinations.iteritems()]
```